# Change the contents on button tap in button group bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, buttongroup

[image]

I want to to change the contents below of button group on tap of every button in button group.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton ">Section1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton active">Section2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section3</button>
</div>
```

I don't want load entire page completely. Just contents below should be changed.

A existing example is http://sourcebits.com/app-development-portfolio/ segmented control. is there any easy way to implement that using html and javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create separate `div` container for each section you have and give it an id attribute. Then, on each button in the button group, you attach an attribute that indicates which `div` it shall render when the button is clicked.

**Demo (using JQuery):**

```js
$(function() {

  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    //hide all sections
    $(".content-section").hide();
    //show the section depending on which button was clicked
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-section")).show();
  });

});
```

```css
.content-section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
  <button type="button" data-section="section1" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton ">Section1</button>
  <button type="button" data-section="section2" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section2</button>
  <button type="button" data-section="section3" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section3</button>
</div>

<div class="content-section" id="section1">
  <h1> Section 1 </h1>
  <p>Section 1 Content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="section2">
  <h1> Section 2 </h1>
  <p>Section 2 Content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="section3">
  <h1> Section 3 </h1>
  <p>Section 3 Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it okay to add all the contents in single html file or can we move to different file? In source bits,if you observe the url changes on tap.